# NSArray elements from parsed .xml file not accessible on iPhone, using TouchXML

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray, touchxml

I have an `NSMutableArray *myArray`, wich is the result of a properly .xml parsed file, using `TouchXML`.

I just want to extract all elements with key `name` and store then in a separate `NSMutableArray`, but my final `NSMutableArray *namesList` is not accessible, crashing my iPhone app right away, because it only contains the last enumerated string and not the whole array.

Here is the code:

```
NSMutableArray *namesList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:myArray copyItems:YES];

       int i;
        for (i = 0; i < [myArray count]; i++) 
           {
            namesList = [[myArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"name"];
            NSLog(@"All Names: %@", namesList);    
           }

          NSLog(@"First Name: %@", [namesList objectAtIndex:0]); <-- crashing line
```

And here is the NSLog:

```
-[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a42540
2012-04-04 10:34:07.882 Sections[3610:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a42540'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this:

```
NSMutableArray * namesList = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(i = 0; i < [myArray count]; i++)
{ 

    NSString * tempString = [NSString stringWithString:[[myArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"name"]];
    [namesList addobject:tempString];
}

 NSLog(@"First Name: %@", [namesList objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

`[[myArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"name"];` returns an `NSString` object and not another array therefore you can't send an `objectAtIndex` to it. Check the structure of your arrays.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Then I have a new question: how to save each NSString in a new NSArray?